# Changing ic_launcher.png caused app to be corrupt

Tags: android, installation, corrupt

I just made my first Android app.  It is very simple.

I emailed the apk file to myself and installed it on my phone, and it worked.

Then I tried to change the icon 
res->New Image Assest and changed the default icon with a png file.

created a new apk and email / install
But this time it says:

```
App not installed.
The package appears to be corrupt.
```

I don't know how to put it back.

One thing I noticed when I create the new Image asses was I had to pick Legacy Only

When I tried to save it as (Adaptive and Legacy):

```
Project must target API 26 or later to use adaptive icons
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can try to **Build > Clean Project** then **Build > Rebuild** Project
and after that if there isn't any errors on the build **delete the app icon** and follow the following steps to add a new app icon to your app:

> - 1 - Locate mipmap-folder (app > res > mipmap)
> - 2 - Right click, New > Image Asset (or you can simply copy paste into the folder)
> - 3 - Go to app > manifests > AndroidManifest.xml and locate android:icon=”@mipmap/ic_launcher“, change "ic_launcher" to the image name you just added

If it still not working try deleting **.gradle**, **.idea** folders from your project root folder and restart Android Studio, this will clean any corrupt configurations, folders are hidden so depending on Windows or Mac you need to enable hidden folders

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that after changing the app icon you **select both *v1 (Jar signature)* and *v2 (Full apk signature)*** while in Generate Signed APK window.

The *Project must target API 26 or later to use adaptive icons* error you need to make sure that your build.gradle(Module: app) file has the following lines:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 26
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out if the Build Variant is debug it works, and if it is release it gives me the corrupt message.

I will keep looking at the differences to see what the problem is.